# Stuck in log in screen in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 as my operating system and I can't log in to my computer.
When I turn on the pc and get to the login screen, I type my password and press ENTER. The screen goes off for a second and it plays a sound (like error sound or something) and it gives me back **the login screen again**

The computer worked fine and the last thing I did before it happened was: sudo reboot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is should be on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem was to install nvidia display driver

Answer (score 0):

First please first check your environment variables are properly configured or not in: **/etc/environment** , that might be the issue or,

also check into **/etc/fstab**, By entering into recovery mode.

if everything is okay in environment file move to next step. First you should check whether the environment files are configured properly or not.